# System.IO.FileLoadException with Microsoft.Identity.Client

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using Graph to send Emails.
In VS2019 it runs great but when placed on production the mail part crashes with the following error: (from windows.log, shortened)

"Toepassing: CIP.WindowsClient.exe Framework-versie: v4.0.30319 Beschrijving: het proces is beëindigd als gevolg van een onverwerkte uitzondering. Uitzonderingsinformatie: System.IO.FileLoadException bij Microsoft.Identity.Client.ApplicationConfiguration..ctor() bij Microsoft.Identity.Client.ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(System.String) bij CIP.Helper.Mail.GraphMail+<"

I placed all the DLL's but no luck.

My code is

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;


namespace CIP.Helper.Mail
{
public class GraphMail
{
    private static GraphServiceClient _userClient;
    private static User _user;

    public GraphMail()
    {
        InitializeGraphForUserAuth();
    }

    private async static void InitializeGraphForUserAuth()
    {
        string auth = string.Concat("https://login.microsoftonline.com/", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TenantId"]);

        
            IConfidentialClientApplication application = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"])
                          .WithClientSecret(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"])
                          .WithAuthority(new Uri(auth))
                          .Build();


            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(string.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TenantId"].ToString()));                            

            try
            {
                _userClient = new GraphServiceClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
                    new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) =>
                    {
                        AuthenticationResult AuthToken = await application.AcquireTokenForClient(new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" }).ExecuteAsync();
                        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", AuthToken.AccessToken);
                    }
                    ));
            }
            catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
            {
                // The application doesn't have sufficient permissions.
                // - Did you declare enough app permissions during app creation?
                // - Did the tenant admin grant permissions to the application?
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", ex.Message);
            }
            catch (MsalServiceException ex) when (ex.Message.Contains("AADSTS70011"))
            {
                // Invalid scope. The scope has to be in the form "https://resourceurl/.default"
                // Mitigation: Change the scope to be as expected.
                Console.WriteLine("Scope provided is not supported");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
            }
        //}
        //catch (FileLoadException ex)
        //{
        //    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.ToString());
        //}
        //catch(Exception ex)
        //{
        //    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.ToString());
        //}

    }
   
}
}
```

In my app.config I've:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.net>
<defaultProxy>
  <proxy bypassonlocal="true" usesystemdefault="false" />
</defaultProxy>
</system.net>
<startup>
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2" />
</startup>
<appSettings>        
<add key="TenantId" value="<guid>"/>
<add key="ClientId" value="<guid>"/>
<add key="ClientSecret" value="<value>"/>
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Als the ID's are loaded correctly (checked)

I can't figure out what the cause is.

Searching suggests that the file is dameged, but I've replaced it with fresh files with no effect.

Any suggestions?

Jeroen

Comment: Remove all files in  the release directory and build again. Then test from release. If correct remove all files from production and copy all files from release directory. Then test.

Comment: Removing all files from production and copy again solved it. Still vague what files caused it.